# __del__method not executing when involving circular reference

Tags: python, circular-reference, del

I find that custom `__del__` method seems not to execute when circular referencing are involved.

Here is a sample code:

```
class DelClass():
        def __init__(self,a):
            self.prop = a 

        def __del__(self):
            print 'del'



if __name__ == "__main__":

    dc1 = DelClass(None)
    dc2 = DelClass(dc1)#dc2 referring to dc1
    dc1.prop = dc2#dc1 referring to dc2, thus creating circular reference
    del dc1#not executing the custom __del__ method

    dc = DelClass(1)
    del dc#executing the custom __del__ method
```

Why this happens?

**Edit:**
Thanks to BrenBarn. I found the reason.

`del something` only decrements the reference count of `something` by 1.

`__del__` will only execute when the reference count reaches 0.

Here is a test code:

```
import gc

class DelClass():
    def __init__(self,name,a):
        self.name = name
        self.prop = a

    def __del__(self):
        print '#####deleting',self.name

dc1 = DelClass("dc1",None)
dc2 = DelClass("dc2",dc1)#dc2 referring to dc1
dc1.prop = dc2#dc1 referring to dc2, thus creating circular reference
print "before deleting dc1,reference count:",len(gc.get_referrers(dc1))
del dc1#not executing the custom __del__ method
print "after deleting dc1, reference count:",len(gc.get_referrers(dc2.prop))
print "deleting the reference held by dc2"
del dc2.prop
print dc2
```

The output is:

```
before deleting dc1,reference count: 2
after deleting dc1, reference count: 1
deleting the reference held by dc2
#####deleting dc1
<__main__.DelClass instance at 0x9316dec>
#####deleting dc2
```

And another question appears:

why the last line(`#####deleting dc2`) in the output happens?

Some implicit `del` operation happens?

Answer (score 3):

Read the [documentation for `__del__`](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__del__) and [for the garbage collector](http://docs.python.org/library/gc.html#gc.garbage).  `__del__` doesn't do what you probably think it does, nor does `del`.  `__del__` is not necessarily called when you do a `del`, and may never be called in case of circular references.  All `del` does is decrement the reference count by 1.

Answer (score 2):

This is not true anymore since python 3.4. See [PEP-442](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0442/).

Answer (score 1):

Because the garbage collector has no way of knowing which can safely be deleted first.

Answer (score 1):

Read this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6104535/i-dont-understand-this-python-del-behaviour). I think this will help you.

> `del` doesn't call `__del__`
>
> `del` in the way you are using removes a local variable. `__del__` is called when the object is destroyed. Python as a language makes no guarantees as to when it will destroy an object.

----Update Edit----

Answer to `Some implicit del operation happens?`

Read this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9796689/379941) will help you

> Python doesn't make any guarantees about when `__del__` is called, or whether it is called at all. As it is, `__del__` methods are unlikely to be called if the object is part of a reference cycle, because even if the cycle as a whole is cleaned up, Python has no way to decide where to break the cycle and in what order the `__del__` methods (if any) should be called. Because of `__del__`'s rather quirky semantics (in order to call `__del__` the refcount of the object is temporarily increased, and the `__del__` method can prevent destruction of the object by storing the reference somewhere else) what happens in other implementations is a bit of a crapshoot. (I don't remember the exact details in current Jython, but it has changed a few times in the past.)
>
> That said, in CPython, if `__del__` is called, it's called as soon as the reference count drops to zero (since refcounting is the only way `__del__` methods are called, and the only chance CPython has of calling `__del__` is when the actual refcount is changed.)